# (function eval () {}) throws a syntax error  if function body is in strict mode?

Tags: javascript, theory

Why does this code throw an error?

```
// global non-strict code
(function eval () { 'use strict'; });
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/SE3eX/1/

So, what we have here is a named function expression. I'd like to explicitly point out that this function expression appears in non-strict code. As you can see, its function body is strict code.

The strict mode rules are here: http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C

The relevant bullet is this one (it's the last one on the list):

> It is a SyntaxError to use within strict mode code the identifiers eval or arguments as the Identifier of a FunctionDeclaration or FunctionExpression or as a formal parameter name (13.1). Attempting to dynamically define such a strict mode function using the Function constructor (15.3.2) will throw a SyntaxError exception.

Notice how this rule only applies if the function declaration/expression itself appears in strict code, which it does *not* in my example above.

But it still throws an error? Why?

Comment: Just totally guessing here, but maybe it has something to do with the fact that in an *expression*, a function instantiation expression with a name binds that name only *within* the function; in other words, it's internally as if there were some magic way for a `var` declaration to create a local variable initialized with a reference to the function. Thus, it's as if you were attempting to bind the global symbol "eval" locally.

Comment: @Pointy Good hint. I'll have to check the standard to establish what exactly is going on in that scenario...

Comment: You get the same error message (SyntaxError: Function name may not be eval or arguments in strict mode) with only `function eval () { 'use strict'; };`

Comment: And this works without syntax error: `window.eval = function () { 'use strict'; };`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[§13.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) outlines what ought to happen in cases such as yours:

> - It is a SyntaxError if any Identifier value occurs more than once within a FormalParameterList of a strict mode FunctionDeclaration or
>     FunctionExpression.
> - It is a SyntaxError if the Identifier "eval" or the Identifier "arguments" occurs within a - FormalParameterList of a strict mode
>     FunctionDeclaration or FunctionExpression.
> - **It is a SyntaxError if the Identifier "eval" or the Identifier "arguments" occurs as the Identifier of a strict mode
>     FunctionDeclaration or FunctionExpression.**

Emphasis mine. Your strict-mode function's *identifier* is `eval`, thus, it's a `SyntaxError`. Game over.

---

To see why the above is a "strict mode function expression," look at the semantic definitions in §13 (Function Definition):

> The production
>   *FunctionExpression* : `function` *Identifier*<sub>opt</sub> `(` *FormalParameterList*<sub>opt</sub> `) {` *FunctionBody* `}`
>    is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Return the result of creating a new Function object as specified in 13.2 with parameters specified by FormalParameterListopt and body
>      specified by FunctionBody. Pass in the LexicalEnvironment of the
>      running execution context as the Scope. **Pass in true as the Strict
>      flag if the FunctionExpression is contained in strict code or if its
>      FunctionBody is strict code.**

Emphasis mine. The above shows how a function expression (or declaration) becomes strict. What it says (in plain English) is that a *FunctionExpression* is `strict` in two scenarios:

1. It's called from a `use strict` context.
2. Its function body begins with `use strict`.

Your confusion arises from thinking that only the **function body** is `strict`, when in fact, the entire **function expression** is `strict`. Your logic, while intuitive, is not how JS works.

---

If you're wondering why ECMAscript works this way, it's pretty simple. Suppose we have this:

```
// look ma, I'm not strict
(function eval() {
     "use strict";
     // evil stuff
     eval(); // this is a perfectly legal recursive call, and oh look...
             // ... I implicitly redefined eval() in a strict block
     // evil stuff
})();
```

Thankfully, the above code will throw because the entire *function expression* is flagged as `strict`.

Comment: nailed it. that's exactly what's happening here

Comment: So a function expression that occurs in non-strict code, but whose function body is strict code, is a "strict mode function expression"? Could you find this definition in the standard, please?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.1.1 - "Function code that is part of a FunctionDeclaration, FunctionExpression, or accessor PropertyAssignment **is strict function code** if its FunctionDeclaration, **FunctionExpression**, or PropertyAssignment is contained in strict mode code or **if the function code begins with a Directive Prologue that contains a Use Strict Directive**."

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - amended my answer.

Comment: @Pete Hm, that definition defines the term "strict function code", which is not the same as a "strict mode function". The former refers to code within a function, while the latter refers to the function itself.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas /sigh. The ECMAScript specification is a nightmare. I'm about ready to revert to my original explanation (see my answer).

Comment: @Pete I know `-.-`. I would love to see the definition "strict mode function === function whose body is strict code". That definition is certainly intuitive, and we both assume it's true, but still... such a definition appears to not exist in the standard.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - actually, it IS in the standard. Read the definitions in §13 (the one I quoted above) and remember that a FunctionExpression contains FunctionBody, per the definition.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco Yes, I see it now. The *Strict* flag which is used during function creation, signals whether the newly created function will be a strict or non-strict function. And the semantic algorithms of the *FunctionDeclaration*, and *FunctionExpression* productions state that a `true` value is passed as the *Strict* flag, if either the function declaration/expression occurs in strict code, or its function body is strict code. I got it! `:)`

Answer (score 3):

Great question!

So to find the answer to your problem you actually need to look at the [process for declaring a function](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) (specifically, steps 3-5 -- emphasis added):

> 1. *...*
> 2. *...*
> 3. Call the CreateImmutableBinding concrete method of *envRec* passing the String value of *Identifier* as the argument.
> 4. Let *closure* be the result of creating a new Function object as specified in 13.2 with parameters specified by *FormalParameterList<sub>opt</sub>* and body specified by *FunctionBody*. Pass in *funcEnv* as the *Scope.* **Pass in true as the *Strict* flag** if the *FunctionExpression* is contained in strict code or **if its *FunctionBody is strict code.***
> 5. **Call the InitializeImmutableBinding concrete method of envRec passing the String value of Identifier and closure as the arguments.**

So, what happens is that your use of eval isn't a problem when the binding gets created in step 3, but once it hits step 5, it's attempting to initialize the binding of `eval` within a strict lexical environment (i.e. assigning something to `eval`), which is not allowed because we're in a strict context following step 4.

Remember that the restriction is not on initializing a new `eval` variable. It's on using it as the *LeftHandSideExpression* of an Assignment operator, which is what happens in step 5 of the function declaration process.

**UPDATE:**

As @DavidTitarenco pointed out, this is explicitly covered in section [13.1](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.1) (in addition to the implicit restriction in section [13](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13)).

Comment: Hm, I don't think that `InitializeImmutableBinding` utilizes the assignment operator. The assignment operator "exists" in the source code, whereas `InitializeImmutableBinding` is an internal method. I doubt that it's defined *in* JavaScript.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas you're right. It doesn't appear to violate the letter of the spec, but it does seem to violate the *spirit* of the spec. Which is something you have to take into account on an all-too-regular basis with ECMAScript. :-/ (that's code for, "your guess is as good as mine" -- I wish I could upvote this question twice).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that it throws an error because inside the function eval would point to the function itself which now is in violation of the strict mode.